# How to remove attribute 'type' from addJs method in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using Prestashop 1.6. I need to remove "type='text/javascript'" form all included JS files. I've tried to check method $this->context->controller->addJS() but there is no any code for attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this file (but not recommended):

themes/javascript.tpl

Note: also you have to clear PrestaShop cache from BO